# Converting .accdb database to .db2

Tags: ms-access, db2

I have some Microsoft Access .accdb databases which I would like to convert to .db2 database format. What's the best way to go about doing this? Would I need to write my own script? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as the ".db2 database format". You will need to somehow generate the `create table` statements for your Access database and extract all data, then create a DB2 database, execute the `create table` statements and load or import data using the corresponding DB2 utility.

Comment: SQL server eventually stores it files in mdf. You could in theory by-pass the server that reads/writes such files and convert directly to/from such formats. The AS400 database (DB2) also has a file format for such files. however you are correct that for all practical purposes one does not "convert" to such server side file formats, but one would connect to the data base engine (say with ODBC) and transfer data. So while there are certainly SQL server formats, or Oracle formats, or MySQL formats, or in this case DB2 file formats, conversion to such file formats while possible is not practical.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal -- that's pure speculation. I could argue with your every statement but it's a waste of time.

Comment: There is ZERO speculation on my part. Spent 10+ years working on mainframe database systems and  including file dumps of such databases. SQL server, Oracle etc ALL SAVE data into files on the hard drive. They have a given file format and in most cases even a given file extension. In this context they ALL HAVE known file formats like dbaseII on a PC and work no different. If file formats are known then reading + converting of such files can occur WITHOUT the server base data engine. Such is BASIC FACT as to how computers and database systems have worked for the last 50 years.

Answer (score 1):

One common approach for exporting Access tables to other database platforms is to install an ODBC driver for the target platform and then use the "External Data > Export > ODBC Database" option in Access to push the tables into the other database.

Comment: This makes the most sense. DB2 is IBM's as400 platform, and Access should be able to 'link" to the DB2 tables after the DB2 odbc drivers are installed.